# OnKeyDown event incorrect encoding

Tags: gwt, character-encoding

I catch all the character typed while the document is receiving focus using following code:

```
RootPanel.get().addDomHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
                char key = (char) event.getNativeKeyCode();
                String keyString = String.valueOf(key);
                if (!event.isShiftKeyDown())
                    keyString = keyString.toLowerCase();
                System.out.print(keyString);

            }
        }, KeyDownEvent.getType());
```

When the device that is sending key events is using ASCII (we cannot control what encoding gets used) then we get the following output:

`www¾mitcom¾m3`

What can we do so that we get the correctly encoded input in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.getNativeKeyCode()` gives you a key code, which is not a character. From documentation: *Gets the key code (code associated with the physical key) associated with this event.*. Dot pressed on my keyboard gives me `190`. Also to mention in Java `char` is 16-bit type, while int is 32-bit, i.e. generally `(char) integerVal` is an unsafe operation.

Now what you probably want to use is `event.getNativeEvent().getCharCode()`. The problem is that it's always `0` in `KeyDownEvent`. Therefore, I would suggest to use `KeyPressHandler & KeyPressEvent`. Your code would look like:

```
private void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
  char c = (char) event.getNativeEvent().getCharCode();
  String s = String.valueOf(c);
  if (event.isShiftKeyDown()) {
    s = s.toUpperCase();
  }

  GWT.log(s);
}

RootPanel.get().addDomHandler(this::onKeyPress, KeyPressEvent.getType());
```

Comment: This is a very beautiful answer. Thanks.